# Как через Web App приложение в Телеграм ответить пользователю в чат

Tags: javascript, php, telegram-bot, telegram, web-apps

Создаю Web Apps приложение в телеграм. По сути, у бота есть кнопка, которая во встроенном в телегрм браузере открывает мой сайт. Сайт работает, все элементы, кнопки на сайте работают. Я хочу чтобы, при определнных действиях, допустим отправка формы на сайте, пользователю в этот же чат из которого он запускает Web Apps приложение, отправлялся мой текст.

На сайте есть подключение js кода телеграм:

`<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>`

Затем идет ниже в коде мы получаем объект webapp

`let tg = window.Telegram.WebApp; //получаем объект webapp телеграма`

После этого я имею доступ ко многим переменным, информация о пользователе к премеру, могу эти данные использовать, выводить в своем Web Apps приложении и т.д.

Читал мануал по работе на сайте телеграмма. Нашел способ отправки, но он работет через кнопки клавиатуры, а мне нужно чтобы прям из браузера WebApp отправилось в чат, знаю это можно, видел в других ботах, но не вижу об этом в статье.

Необходимо на js или php, как это возможно, отправить пользователю сообщение (текст), нужна просто функция или команда для отправки, чтобы когда пользователь закроет окно Web App, в чате останется мое текстовое сообщение.

Answer (score 0):

У меня вроде все получилось, работает. Там немного была путаница в понятиях, чтобы отправить ответ от бота клиенту, мне нужен был apikey и chatid.

Вот моя функция для отправки сообщений клиенту

```
function request($ApiKey, $method, $data = array())
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $ApiKey .  '/' . $method);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST'); //Отправляем через POST
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); //Сами данные отправляемые

    $out = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true); //Получаем результат выполнения, который сразу расшифровываем из JSON'a в массив для удобства

    curl_close($curl); //Закрываем курл

    return $out; //Отправляем ответ в виде массива
}
```

Проблема была в том, что у меня не было chat_id, а оказалось, что в WebApp приложении есть

```
let tg = window.Telegram.WebApp; //получаем объект webapp телеграма
tg.initDataUnsafe.user.id // вот этот юзер id = chatid, я думал это что-то другое, в документации это описано как уникальный id юзера, но он совпадает с chatid, я проверил.
```

Следовательно, подставляю в свою функцию все эти переменные (плюс клавиатуру, плюс само сообщение) и все прекрасно работает.